# Changing X-axis DateTime Intervals in Matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

[image]

I browsed over stack overflow and found some matching questions, but I could not gather much from them.

I have a dataset as shown in the image above.

The dataset consists of Sales figures from Jan 1949 to Dec 1960. I want to plot the Date vs Sales graph. My code returned the following graph. [image]

The X-axis shows only intervals of 2 years. I want the x-Axis to display at uniform intervals through the date range of Jan 1949 to Dec 1960 (as shown in the dataset above), rotated in a vertical format to accomodate more xticks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator i.e. something like:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
...
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```